# AWS Python Lambda Function JSON format

Tags: python, json, aws-lambda

I am using the following Python function in AWs Lambda:

```
import json
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr

#always start with the lambda_handler
def lambda_handler(event, context):

    # make the connection to dynamodb
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

    # select the table
    table = dynamodb.Table("test")

    response = table.query(
    KeyConditionExpression=Key('coursename').eq('intro')
    )
    data = response['Items']
    return {'body' : data}
```

It outputs the following JSON - notice the "body" key? This is creating some issues when I try to use the response in my app because I have to reference the "body" as part of the response.

**JSON response from Lambda**

```
{
    "body": [{
        "coursename": "introto1",
        "course-lesson-name": "Welcome to One! "
    }, {
        "coursename": "introto2",
        "course-lesson-name": "What is One?"
    }, {
        "coursename": "introto2",
        "course-lesson-name": "What Can We do with One?"
    }]
}
```

This is the JSON format I need my Python function to output. Can this be done in AWS Lambda?

**JSON format I need:**

```
[{
    "coursename": "introto1",
    "course-lesson-name": "Welcome to One! "
}, {
    "coursename": "introto2",
    "course-lesson-name": "What is One?"
}, {
    "coursename": "introto2",
    "course-lesson-name": "What Can We do with One?"
}]
```

Comment: What happens if you change `return {'body' : data}` to `return data` ?

Comment: Dang - that easy, huh? I feel a little foolish, but thanks - it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response is in that format because you are explicitly wrapping it in a JSON object with a `body` property. Change `return {'body' : data}` to `return data`.